# Starting or Installing a Windows-Service with a parameter

Tags: c#, windows-services, administration

I created a new Windows-Service, that requires a simple string as a Parameter in c#.
I installed the Service on Windows Server 2008 R2 and I can add the Parameter in the service-properties. The Service recoginizes the Parameter, when I start the Service manually via the property-window. But after restarting the Service, the Parameter is lost.
Can I pass the Parameter while installing the Service or how can I manipulate the start-behaviour regarding the Parameter afterwards. I want to avoid to do any changes to the registry. As far as I know it's not possible to add custom Parameters to installutil.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know. There is now way to add a Parameter to a Service without changing the "imagepath" in the registry.